# ChocolateChip-ui button navigation

Tags: cordova, chocolatechip-ui

I'm try to implement my cordova app with chui, and having some navigation problems (new to chui so I must be missing something).
I'm using slideout menu, and one of the articles is "order now" which saves new orders to parse.com, so my view js code looks like:

```
var OrderObject = Parse.Object.extend("OrderObject_1");
var order = new OrderObject();
order.save({
            fullname:   _fullname,
            address:    _address,
            date:       _date,
            phone:      _phone,
            done:       false
        }, {
            success: function(object) {
                $(".success").show();
                $.UIGoToArticle('my_orders_article');
            }
```

The parse object is saved, and I can see the success message shows, but the `$.UIGoToArticle('my_orders_article');` doesn't seem to do anything.
I do have the needed article:

```
<nav>
    <h1>Orders</h1>
</nav>
<article id='my_orders_article' class="navigable">
    <section>
        <h2>Stuff for my orders</h2>
    </section>
</article>
```

I saw some complains about SlideOut and button navigation together, but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this script?

```
$.UIGoToArticle('#my_orders_article');
```

You can read the documentation here: http://chocolatechip-ui.com/documentation/chuijs.html